# How to delete an object with validation in a group of many objects

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

I have a template that displays a set of "Team" instances in a table, each with a delete button like

```
Team
Ducks [Delete]
Bears [Delete]
Hawks [Delete]
Dogs  [Delete]
...
```

When a user clicks one of the delete buttons, I want to run some validation on the team instance, checking things like "is this team tied to any existing games".  If the validation is successful, I want to delete the team, but if it's unsuccessful I want to re-render the form with the validation error.

I tried doing this with the following pseudo code:

```
for team in teams:
    render teamdeleteform (see below) with action = "deleteteam/{{team.id}}/"
```

The problem I'm having is, if a user tried to delete the Bears and this raises a validation error, every form in the template is going to be displayed with that error. How can I render each form but only display the validation error on the form that was originally posted?

forms.py

```
class TeamDeleteForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Team

    def clean(self):
        # Check to see if this team is tied to any existing games
        raise ValidationError("This is a dummy validation error!")
        return cleaned_data
```

views.py

```
class TeamDeleteView(LeagueContextMixin, FormView):
    form_class = TeamDeleteForm
    template_name = "leagueapp/editleague.html"

    def get_success_url(self):
        team = Team.objects.get(pk = self.kwargs['team_id'])
        return "/league/editleague/" + str(team.league.id)

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        # Overwrite the deleteform retrieved from LeagueContextMixin's get_context_data method with the 'form' form that's being edited 
        # and remove the 'form' form from the context using pop()
        context['deleteteamform'] = context.pop('form')
        return super().render_to_response(context, **response_kwargs)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^deleteteam/(?P<team_id>\d+)/$', views.TeamDeleteView.as_view(), name="deleteTeam"),
)
```